# Unity загрузка спрайта из сети

Tags: c#, unity3d

Здравствуйте, как в Unity объекту UI Image присвоить спрайт из сети, по определенной ссылке? Или как его можно загрузить в проект и сохранить в нем для дальнейшего использования? В Runtime. Спасибо.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.LoadImageIntoTexture.html первая же ссылка из google. Попытайтесь прежде чем задавать вопрос сами как-то с ним разобраться. По идее должно и в редакторе и в runtime работать

Comment: Только не `WWW`, а https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.html используйте.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!